# Standard method for file distribution prior to MPI execution

Tags: file, mpi, cluster-computing

I am new to the world of MPI and HPC in general. I have designed a distributed algorithm which I have implemented using MPI. Each MPI process accesses a set of files which is different for each MPI process. On my computer this already works because the files are already there.

The problem comes now that I want to run the program on more than one computer because I need to transfer files to each workstation manually and then run my program. This is okay for one or two computers because I can do it by hand but what happens if I have 1000 computers and I want to distribute files to each computer before running my program.

Is there a generally acceptable/standard way of transferring files from a host node in a cluster to all the destination nodes prior to running the actual MPI program?

**UPDATE**
As an example Matlab has a batch distritbution function argument called [FileDependencies](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/filedependencies.html) which zips relevant file on the host machine and distributes them to the nodes and then unzips them into a file structure on those machines.

Comment: Sounds like you need some sort of cluster or grid middleware. Could something like globus or condor be what you are asking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually with a shared file system, like NFS.

**Edit**:  MPI is generally used for parallel programs that require tight coupling (high performance computing).  It sounds like there is no coupling among your tasks, you just want a lot running at once.  This type of computing is called high-throughput computing, or embarrassingly parallel computing.   The most widely used platform for HTC is [Condor](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/condor/), it even has a file transfer mechanism built in (just list the files you want to transfer, and they'll end up on your execute hosts).

Comment: The nodes I will be deploying on are on different networks in at least 3 different cities (same country). I was hoping there was a more standard way of distributing files...

Comment: If your tasks are running on different networks, then maybe MPI isn't the way to go.  Have you looks at an HTC solution, like Condor?  http://research.cs.wisc.edu/condor  PS: Condor has a file transfer mechanism built in.

Comment: That is basically the answer I was looking for. Can you update your answer so that I can accept it?